# Scala class with constructor requiring parameter of the same Class type

Tags: scala

I can't remember but recently in one of the APIs I saw something like this `class A (member:A){}`. Scala does support it and there is no problem creating such a class but how do we initiate it and what purpose would such a class serve?

Answer (score 2):

Something like `var childNode = new Node(parentNode)`.  You'd use it whenever you want a reference to anything of the same type.  In this case, it might be reasonable to allow a null-valued parameter:

```
var root = new Node(null)
var child = new Node(root)
```

Comment: The class `Node` as per the need in question should expect a parameter of type `Node` or it's subclass, I don't think we can pass an instance of parent class to it. I tried it in REPL and it doesn't work. `>>class C {def cfunc = println("cfunc")} >>class B (member:B) extends C {def bfunc = println("bfunc")} >>val c = new C()` `val b = new B(c) >><console>:10: error: type mismatch;
 found   : C
 required: B
       val b = new B(c)`

Comment: There's no reference to parent/child classes in the question or in my answer.  In my answer, the _objects_ have a parent/child relationship, not the classes.